Test function for array elements values check, not removing
I'm trying to wave out all the bad situations with the elements of my array. But unfortunately my JavaScript code doesn't work as one piece: it works correctly with a separate "IF" selectors but not all together. Could anybody explain me whats the issue? Thanks a lot in advance!
Here is the code:
/** Check the elements of the array on:
* The array is empty
* Array element/s is/are not a numbers
* Among elements there is not an integers
* Among elements there is a negative number/s
* Among elements there is a too large numbers
*/
const parbaude = (mas) => {
    var response = [true, "... No problem found!"];
    if (mas.length == 0) {
        response = [false, "... Your array is empty!"];
    } else if (mas.filter(item => typeof item !== 'number')) {
        response = [false, "... Only numbers are allowed!"];
    } else if (mas.filter(item => !Number.isInteger(item))) {
        response = [false, "... Enter integer only!"];
    } else if (Math.min(...mas) <= 0) {
        response = [false, "... Only positive numbers are allowed!"];
    } else if (Math.max(...mas) > 1000) {
        response = [false, "... The number is too large: n < 1000!"];
    } else {
        // Return the test result
        return response;
    }
};
//  !!! Try each of these options !!!
//const mas = [];
//const mas = [3, 'd', 7, 9];
//const mas = [3, 4.6, 7, 9];
const mas = [3, -4, 7, 9];
//const mas = [3, 4000, 7, 9];
//const mas = [3, 4, 7, 9];
document.getElementById("izvade").innerHTML = parbaude(mas);


filter will return an empty array if no matches and if ([]) ... is true.

return response should not be inside an else clause; you always want to return it.    Also you can't set an array (your return value) as a DOM element's innerHTML

You don't need multiple if-else-if change response =  to return .  You could also change to a switch.   Note also, if you number is exactly 1000 you won't get the error saying it has to be less than 1000.   Updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/b62tfadv/

Here is the corrected JS:
First, the return should not be in the else because it will not be processed if one of the above conditions (if) is met.
Second is your condition for number and integer. You could check every item in the array if all met the criteria then add the ! before the statement to indicate the opposite (false).
Lastly, though you can confirm this one. Your condition for negative is <=0 but 0 is not negative so I removed =. You can keep it though depending on your requirement.
Here is the working code:


/** Check the elements of the array on:
* The array is empty
* Array element/s is/are not a numbers
* Among elements there is not an integers
* Among elements there is a negative number/s
* Among elements there is a too large numbers
*/
const parbaude = (mas) => {
    var response = [true, "... No problem found!"];
    if (mas.length == 0) {
        response = [false, "... Your array is empty!"];
    } else if (!mas.every(item => typeof item === 'number')) {
        response = [false, "... Only numbers are allowed!"];
    } else if (!mas.every(Number.isInteger)) {
        response = [false, "... Enter integer only!"];
    } else if (Math.min(...mas) < 0) {
        response = [false, "... Only positive numbers are allowed!"];
    } else if (Math.max(...mas) > 1000) {
        response = [false, "... The number is too large: n < 1000!"];
    }
    // Return the test result
    return response;
};
//  !!! Try each of these options !!!
let mas;
const span = document.getElementById("izvade");

mas = [];
span.innerHTML += parbaude(mas) + '<br>';
mas = [3, 'd', 7, 9];
span.innerHTML += parbaude(mas) + '<br>';
mas = [3, 4.6, 7, 9];
span.innerHTML += parbaude(mas) + '<br>';
mas = [3, -4, 7, 9];
span.innerHTML += parbaude(mas) + '<br>';
mas = [3, 4000, 7, 9];
span.innerHTML += parbaude(mas) + '<br>';
mas = [3, 4, 7, 9];
span.innerHTML += parbaude(mas) + '<br>';
<span id="izvade"></span>




Thanks a lot! It helps me to understand lots of important details...
